# How to make the filtered search result to display in listview(android)

Tags: java, android, listview, search

I have a edittext and a listview which contains data in it, so after giving keyword in edittext related keyword from the listview should be displayed. for this i have done the coding.. the problem is filtered search items are displaying in toast as one bye one, but i need it to be displayed in the listview, can anybody tell where m i going wrong?

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
JSONArray posts;



 //ArrayList thats going to hold the search results
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> searchResults;
  LayoutInflater inflater;
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://exm/ads/?json=get_recent_posts";


 static final String KEY_POSTS = "posts";
 static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_ATTACHMENTS = "attachments";
static final String KEY_SLUG = "slug";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
static final String KEY_IMAGES = "images";
static final String KEY_URL = "url";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText searchBox=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    final ListView  list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    //get the LayoutInflater for inflating the customomView
     //this will be used in the custom adapter
     inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);





 final  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        // Creating JSON Parser instance
                final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
                try {
                     posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

        // looping through all song nodes <song>
                for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                    String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                    String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                    // to remove all <P> </p> and <br /> and replace with ""
                     content = content.replace("<br />", "");
                     content = content.replace("<p>", "");
                     content = content.replace("</p>", "");

                    //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                    JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                    String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                    String url = null;
                    String slug = null;
                    try {
                    JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                    for(int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                        slug = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                        JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                        JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                        url = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }




            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, id);
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
            map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug);
            map.put(KEY_URL, url);


            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
                }   
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }


              //searchResults=OriginalValues initially
                searchResults=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(songsList);


         // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);    
             list.setAdapter(adapter);


             searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                   //get the text in the EditText
                   String searchString=searchBox.getText().toString();
                   int textLength=searchString.length();

                          //clear the initial data set
                   searchResults.clear();

                   for(int i=0;i<songsList.size();i++)
                   {
                  String playerName=songsList.get(i).get("title").toString();

                  if(textLength<=playerName.length()){

                  //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                    if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0,textLength)))
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),playerName,1).show();
                    searchResults.add(songsList.get(i));
                  }
                   }

                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }

                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                     int after) {


                   }

                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                   }
                  });
```

Comment: you are not changing the data of the adapter. you need to tell the adapter that the new data is `searchResults`

Comment: Sorry if i had misunderstood wrongly, for changing the data of the adapter this code is used right? adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); @SherifelKhatib

Comment: no, this is not enough you should also change the data of the adapter

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

You are not changing the underlying data in the adapter. You should change the data of the adapter: For example, try to replace

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

with
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, searchResults);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

to Tell the adapter that the new data is `searchResults`.

---

**GOOD SOLUTION**
You shoudl use a [Filter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html) in your adapter to filter the results.

Comment: i added the above code of  urs but still the issue remains the same @Sherif elKhatib